# Using CloudSolrServer as SolrJ client

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

My question is when we are using CloudSolrServer, we specify single zkHost address and LBHttpSolrServer. Now CloudSolrServer does extracts information about alive and dead nodes from zookeeper (zkHost) and serves the requests.
But what if the zkHost specified as argument it self goes down ? I think CloudSolrServer should accept more then one zkHost, as the case with LBHttpSolrServer, which accepts more then one solr server urls.

Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.lucene.solr.user/71075

You can pass a comma-delimited list of Zk addresses in your ensemble, such as:

zk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181, etc.